# Table expanding horizontally causes new blank page

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report like that in the following picture:

[image]

The tablix expands at runtime horizontally due to a couple of columns groupings. What I marked as "Extra blank space" must be there, because otherwise the TextBox in the title where "Expr" appears will appear wrapped at runtime.

At runtime the tablix expands correctly and I sized the columns so that it will draw itself on just one complete page.

The issue is that I get additionally a second page, which is completely blank: I think this is due to the "Extra blank space", which, as explained, I cannot get rid of.

Maybe SSRS is not so clever as to remove this useless Extra blank space and fill it with the expanded tables.

Any suggestion is welcome.
Regards

Comment: What happens if you set the width of your expression label to the width of the matrix component and set the CanGrow to true on the label. I have seen oddities like this before when using short columns and title when the columns don't fill across pass the labels width everything is fine.

Comment: But as far as I know you cannot set the width of an element to an expression with MS SSRS, nor you can bind the width of an element to that of another like WPF, can you?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the design time width the same and set CanGrow=true on the header.

Comment: Thank you lrb. Unfortunately the CanGrow property works only on the item height: item width is static as stated also in [Allow a Text Box to Grow or Shrink (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/a58ea579-4f71-4384-a9ab-c85937e389c2/can-grow-property-is-not-working-in-ssrs-2008-r2)

Answer (score 0):

That "extra space" is not something you need to predetermine in the report. You can instead take the side of the report and slide it up next to the column in the tablix.[image]

The extra space you are providing is telling the report to leave the space there beyond the columns. so if you want it flush you should have the side up against the column.

Comment: I know, I "can instead take the side of the report and slide it up next to the column in the tablix"!  But as I explained, I do need that extra space for two reasons:  
- the TextBox in the header will also expand  
*AND*  
- SSRS has no way to tell an item to expand its **width** instead of its **height**  
Therefore I need to accomodate for extra blank space in the report design, so that the TextBox in the header has all the space it needs.